# Update Multiple Records Efficiently

Tags: mysql, performance, updating

I have a table on my site where the user has the ability to re-order the rows. This part is easy to do with jQuery UI, and getting the new order back is simple using the `$('#sortable').sortable("serialize")` method. My question is now, what's the most efficient way to save all these records in the database, since changing the order of one item changes all the records in the table? I know I could create a new `UPDATE` statement for each row based on their ID, but I feel like there has to be a better way. Is there?

I'm using MySQL and ASP.NET.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to store a specific sort order, correct?

Comment: @eykanal that is correct. I have a column named "rank" where I store the order of the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`START TRANSACTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) command. This is much faster.

Comment: i read that article but it doesn't really explain very well what it does. could you elaborate? does it just commit all the changes at once instead of each command one at a time?

Comment: Yes; if a group of statements are within a transaction, they're all executed together.  Unless you have a very large table, doing a whole set of Updates in a transaction is simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is potentially an arbitrarily large number of rows, I would store the ordering as a text string entry in the user preferences table (assuming you have such a table). Basically, the default would be a null entry (to save on disc space), which would mean that the ordering is unchanged from the ordering in the database, and if the user changes it you could just serialize the order of the rows (i.e., if they had row 15 first, then 19, then 3, you could have `15-19-3`) and then just read it out. It's a single update and it scales indefinitely (well, until the length of the text string, but that's [pretty doggone big](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) for the `mediumtext` and `longtext` types).

---

I'm leaving the above just in case it's applicable to other people, but for the specific case described below, I think I would consider storing the prefs in a textfile. Given that the ordering is shown to the user anyway, there's no security risk in the prefs being in a plaintext file, and you can rewrite the whole thing very quickly. Given how you described it below, I would use a two-column CSV file, but obviously you could set it up however makes the most sense.

A quick search on file reading speeds led to [this comment](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#91414) on the `file_get_contents()` function, which suggests you may want to pay attention to how large the file will be when considering the method you'll use to access the data in the file. I don't know about writing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i'm not sure this is applicable in my case because these aren't just user preferences. these are permanent ordering changes reflected site-wide. for me to implement something like that i would have to do more trickiness, like `1-10;2-8;3-4` etc where one is the id of the record and the second is the rank. While this is definitely doable, I feel like it's not the ideal solution in terms of maintenance.

Comment: @Jason - ah, shows what happens when you make assumptions about other people's site requirements. I updated my answer with another possible suggestion.

Comment: This solution sounds quite interesting. The problem that I see is that if you ever need the ranking in a SQL query you will have a trouble. But that are just assumptions about other people's requirements ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some clarity at least for me. I imagine you show a couple of entries to which I will refer by ID~rank. For example:

```
5~1
6~2
7~3
1~4
24~5
2~6
```

Now you say changing that "the order of one item changes all the records in the table". Is this really necessary in your design? If the user switches the elements with id-s 1 and 24 then you will have the following serialized list:

```
[5~1],[6~2],[7~3],[24~5],[1~4],[2~6]
```

Now by iterating this list you can easily determine which rows should be really updated (this one mismatching the natural order of rank).

In my example you should make two update queries instead of six:

```
update XYZ set rank=4 where id = 24;
update XYZ set rank=5 where id = 1;
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the answer :) what happens if someone moves something from rank 1 to rank 4? doesn't that change rank 2 to rank 1 and rank 3 to 2, etc? it's not as simple as swapping, unfortunately :\

Comment: Of course - moving the first row to the bottom is the worst case scenario, while just a switch is the fastest. This simple method can be improved perhaps if you leave holes into the ranks but it seems that it will not be simple and maintainable anymore...